# Strange errors after checking out project

Tags: android, gradle

I am checking out my project on another computer and I am running into some weird errors with gradle. Here is the complete error output from the console:

```
    03-19 08:28:26.377 239-239/? E/vinput-seamless: found seamless mouse device
    03-19 08:28:26.706 246-246/? E/libEGL: load_driver(/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so): dlopen failed: library "/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so" not found
    03-19 08:28:26.744 246-246/? E/EGL_emulation: Failed to establish connection with the host
    03-19 08:28:26.747 246-246/? E/gralloc_vbox86: gralloc: Failed to get host connection
    03-19 08:28:26.747 246-246/? E/SurfaceFlinger: hwcomposer module not found
    03-19 08:28:26.747 246-246/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ERROR: failed to open framebuffer (I/O error), aborting

                                                   --------- beginning of crash
    03-19 08:28:26.747 246-246/? A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 246 (surfaceflinger)

                                         [ 03-19 08:28:26.747   139:  139 W/         ]
                                         debuggerd: handling request: pid=246 uid=1000 gid=1003 tid=246


                                         [ 03-19 08:28:26.749   277:  277 E/         ]
                                         debuggerd: Unable to connect to activity manager (connect failed: Connection refused)
    03-19 08:28:26.800 277-277/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
    03-19 08:28:26.800 277-277/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'Android/vbox86p/vbox86p:7.1.1/NMF26Q/genymo03202243:userdebug/test-keys'
    03-19 08:28:26.800 277-277/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
    03-19 08:28:26.800 277-277/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'x86'
    03-19 08:28:26.800 277-277/? A/DEBUG: pid: 246, tid: 246, name: surfaceflinger  >>> /system/bin/surfaceflinger <<<
    03-19 08:28:26.800 277-277/? A/DEBUG: signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
    03-19 08:28:26.800 277-277/? A/DEBUG:     eax 00000000  ebx 000000f6  ecx 000000f6  edx 00000006
    03-19 08:28:26.800 277-277/? A/DEBUG:     esi eecf758c  edi eecf7534
    03-19 08:28:26.800 277-277/? A/DEBUG:     xcs 00000023  xds 0000002b  xes 0000002b  xfs 00000003  xss 0000002b
    03-19 08:28:26.800 277-277/? A/DEBUG:     eip eec23bb9  ebp ff8a07b8  esp ff8a075c  flags 00000296
    03-19 08:28:26.800 277-277/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
    03-19 08:28:26.800 277-277/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 00000bb9  [vdso:eec23000] (__kernel_vsyscall+9)
    03-19 08:28:26.800 277-277/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 0007a30c  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+28)
    03-19 08:28:26.800 277-277/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 00075b55  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+85)
    03-19 08:28:26.800 277-277/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 0002786a  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+42)
    03-19 08:28:26.800 277-277/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 0001ee46  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+86)
    03-19 08:28:26.800 277-277/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 0004fcae  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so
    03-19 08:28:26.800 277-277/? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 0003e2f8  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so (_ZN7android14SurfaceFlinger4initEv+1016)
    03-19 08:28:26.800 277-277/? A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 00000e87  /system/bin/surfaceflinger
    03-19 08:28:26.800 277-277/? A/DEBUG:     #08 pc 0001533c  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+108)
    03-19 08:28:26.800 277-277/? A/DEBUG:     #09 pc 00000ccc  /system/bin/surfaceflinger
  ...
    03-19 08:28:36.013 598-617/system_process E/BatteryStatsService: no controller energy info supplied

                                                                     [ 03-19 08:28:36.014   690:  690 D/         ]
                                                                     HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xdd17da40, tid 690
    03-19 08:28:36.081 790-854/com.android.settings E/EGL_emulation: tid 854: eglSurfaceAttrib(1174): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
    03-19 08:28:36.328 770-770/com.android.phone E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null
    03-19 08:28:36.445 690-690/com.android.systemui E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null
    03-19 08:28:36.457 690-690/com.android.systemui E/CameraManagerGlobal: Camera service is unavailable
    03-19 08:28:36.468 690-690/com.android.systemui E/CameraManagerGlobal: Camera service is unavailable
    03-19 08:28:36.950 770-770/com.android.phone E/PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] getCarrierPackageNamesForIntent: No UICC
    03-19 08:28:37.039 770-770/com.android.phone E/PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] getIccId: No UICC
    03-19 08:28:37.048 1129-1129/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
    03-19 08:28:37.048 1129-1129/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
    03-19 08:28:37.486 770-770/com.android.phone E/PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] getIccId: No UICC
    03-19 08:28:37.546 1063-1180/com.android.launcher3 E/libEGL: load_driver(/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so): dlopen failed: library "/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so" not found
    03-19 08:28:37.558 770-770/com.android.phone E/PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] getIccId: No UICC

                                                                          [ 03-19 08:28:37.558  1063: 1180 D/         ]
..
    03-19 08:28:41.779 1735-1735/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
    03-19 08:28:42.241 330-330/? E/EmulatedCamera_GenyClient: receiveMessage: Unable to obtain payload size: Try again
    03-19 08:28:42.241 330-330/? E/EmulatedCamera_GenyClient: doQuery Response to query 'connect' has failed: Try again
    03-19 08:28:42.241 330-330/? E/EmulatedCamera_GenyClient: queryConnect: Query failed: No error message
    03-19 08:28:42.241 330-330/? E/EmulatedCamera_GenyDevice: connectDevice: Connection to device 'back' failed
    03-19 08:28:42.241 330-330/? E/CameraFlashlight: Could not open camera 0: -19
    03-19 08:28:42.241 330-330/? E/CameraFlashlight: connectCameraDevice: initializing camera 0 failed
    03-19 08:28:42.241 330-330/? E/CameraFlashlight: findFlashUnits: failed to check if camera 0 has a flash unit. No such device (-19)
    03-19 08:28:43.052 1319-1740/com.google.android.gms E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.wearable.settings
    03-19 08:28:44.107 1319-1661/com.google.android.gms E/ConfigFileUtils: Failed to read config file: /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/current_modulesets.pb (No such file or directory)
    03-19 08:28:45.553 255-260/? E/Drm: Failed to find drm plugin
    03-19 08:28:45.641 1319-1857/com.google.android.gms E/MDM: [172] wuq.run: Couldn't connect to Google API client: krs{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null, message=null}
    03-19 08:28:45.778 1890-1890/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
    03-19 08:28:46.167 984-1917/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null
    03-19 08:28:46.230 1923-1923/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
    03-19 08:28:46.337 984-984/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null
    03-19 08:28:46.349 1742-1760/com.google.android.gms.unstable E/libEGL: load_driver(/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so): dlopen failed: library "/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so" not found
    03-19 08:28:47.134 1319-1319/com.google.android.gms E/MDM: [1] SitrepChimeraService.a: No Google accounts; deferring server state update.
    03-19 08:28:47.777 984-1688/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/NetworkScheduler.ATC: Received callback from client for task that is already complete. ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.checkin.EventLogService} AggregationTaskTag
    03-19 08:28:48.580 984-1972/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/NetworkScheduler.ATC: Received callback from client for task that is already complete. ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.clearcut.uploader.QosUploaderService} qos_unmetered_periodic
    03-19 08:28:48.587 984-1975/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/NetworkScheduler.ATC: Received callback from client for task that is already complete. ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.clearcut.uploader.QosUploaderService} qos_default_periodic
    03-19 08:28:48.913 1580-1580/com.google.android.configupdater E/ConfigUpdater: Received malformed URL while handling Gservices.CHANGED_ACTION intent_firewall: null null
    03-19 08:28:48.915 1319-1740/com.google.android.gms E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.wearable.settings
    03-19 08:28:48.916 1580-1580/com.google.android.configupdater E/ConfigUpdater: Received malformed URL while handling Gservices.CHANGED_ACTION apn_db: null null
    03-19 08:28:48.917 1580-1580/com.google.android.configupdater E/ConfigUpdater: Received malformed URL while handling Gservices.CHANGED_ACTION tzdata: null null
    03-19 08:28:48.919 1580-1580/com.google.android.configupdater E/ConfigUpdater: Received malformed URL while handling Gservices.CHANGED_ACTION selinux: null null
    03-19 08:28:48.923 1580-1580/com.google.android.configupdater E/ConfigUpdater: Received malformed URL while handling Gservices.CHANGED_ACTION carrier_provisioning_urls: null null
    03-19 08:28:49.042 1319-1319/com.google.android.gms E/ChimeraProxyRslvr: Failed to instantiate com.google.android.gms.checkin.CheckinChimeraService$Receiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.checkin.CheckinChimeraService$Receiver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar", zip file "/system/framework/com.android.media.remotedisplay.jar", zip file "/system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/PrebuiltGmsCore.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_extracted_libs/x86, /system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/x86, /system/fake-libs, /system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/PrebuiltGmsCore.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
    03-19 08:28:49.042 1319-1319/com.google.android.gms E/ChimeraRcvrProxy: com.google.android.gms.checkin.CheckinServiceReceiver dropping broadcast com.google.gservices.intent.action.GSERVICES_CHANGED
    03-19 08:28:49.128 1319-1740/com.google.android.gms E/ProcessCheckinRequest: CheckinNowTaskTag : Checkin Succeeded: https://android.clients.google.com/checkin (request #1): 
    03-19 08:28:49.230 1319-1954/com.google.android.gms E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.wearable.settings
    03-19 08:28:49.232 984-984/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null
    03-19 08:28:49.333 1319-1715/com.google.android.gms E/ConfigFileUtils: Failed to read config file: /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/current_modulesets.pb (No such file or directory)
    03-19 08:28:49.394 984-2011/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/HeterodyneSyncer: expected change count fail
    03-19 08:28:49.556 1319-1661/com.google.android.gms E/ConfigFileUtils: Failed to read config file: /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/current_modulesets.pb (No such file or directory)
    03-19 08:28:49.575 255-260/? E/Drm: Failed to find drm plugin
    03-19 08:28:49.807 1319-1661/com.google.android.gms E/ConfigFileUtils: Failed to read config file: /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/current_modulesets.pb (No such file or directory)

                                                                           [ 03-19 08:28:49.817  1742: 1757 D/         ]
                                                                           HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xe0bb8e40, tid 1757
    03-19 08:28:49.830 984-2020/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/GcmPushIntentOperation: Failed to subscribe to GCM: com.google.android.gms.accountsettings
                                                                                            java.io.IOException: TOO_MANY_SUBSCRIBERS
                                                                                                at uzy.b(:com.google.android.gms@11509470:41)
                                                                                                at uzy.a(:com.google.android.gms@11509470:46)
                                                                                                at uzv.b(:com.google.android.gms@11509470:11)
                                                                                                at uzv.a(:com.google.android.gms@11509470:29)
                                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.phenotype.gcmpush.GcmPushIntentOperation.a(:com.google.android.gms@11509470:22)
                                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.phenotype.gcmpush.GcmPushIntentOperation.a(:com.google.android.gms@11509470:4)
                                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.phenotype.gcmpush.GcmPushIntentOperation.onHandleIntent(:com.google.android.gms@11509470:18)
                                                                                                at com.google.android.chimera.IntentOperation.onHandleIntent(:com.google.android.gms@11509470:2)
                                                                                                at bwh.run(:com.google.android.gms@11509470:10)
                                                                                                at bwe.run(:com.google.android.gms@11509470:14)
                                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                                                                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
    03-19 08:28:50.259 984-2020/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/GcmPushIntentOperation: Failed to subscribe to GCM: com.google.android.gms.audit
                                                                                            java.io.IOException: TOO_MANY_SUBSCRIBERS
                                                                                                at uzy.b(:com.google.android.gms@11509470:41)
                                                                                                at uzy.a(:com.google.android.gms@11509470:46)
                                                                                                at uzv.b(:com.google.android.gms@11509470:11)
                                                                                                at uzv.a(:com.google.android.gms@11509470:29)
                                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.phenotype.gcmpush.GcmPushIntentOperation.a(:com.google.android.gms@11509470:22)
                                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.phenotype.gcmpush.GcmPushIntentOperation.a(:com.google.android.gms@11509470:4)
                                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.phenotype.gcmpush.GcmPushIntentOperation.onHandleIntent(:com.google.android.gms@11509470:18)
                                                                                                at com.google.android.chimera.IntentOperation.onHandleIntent(:com.google.android.gms@11509470:2)
                                                                                                at bwh.run(:com.google.android.gms@11509470:10)
                                                                                                at bwe.run(:com.google.android.gms@11509470:14)
                                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                                                                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
    03-19 08:28:50.439 984-2020/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/GcmPushIntentOperation: Failed to subscribe to GCM: com.google.android.gms.cast
                                                                                            java.io.IOException: TOO_MANY_SUBSCRIBERS
                                                                                                at uzy.b(:com.google.android.gms@11509470:41)
                                                                                                at uzy.a(:com.google.android.gms@11509470:46)
                                                                                                at uzv.b(:com.google.android.gms@11509470:11)
                                                                                                at uzv.a(:com.google.android.gms@11509470:29)
                                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.phenotype.gcmpush.GcmPushIntentOperation.a(:com.google.android.gms@11509470:22)
                                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.phenotype.gcmpush.GcmPushIntentOperation.a(:com.google.android.gms@11509470:4)
                                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.phenotype.gcmpush.GcmPushIntentOperation.onHandleIntent(:com.google.android.gms@11509470:18)
                                                                                                at com.google.android.chimera.IntentOperation.onHandleIntent(:com.google.android.gms@11509470:2)
                                                                                                at bwh.run(:com.google.android.gms@11509470:10)
                                                                                                at bwe.run(:com.google.android.gms@11509470:14)
                                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                                                                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
    03-19 08:28:50.963 255-260/? E/Drm: Failed to find drm plugin
    03-19 08:28:51.002 984-1809/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/NetworkScheduler.ATC: Provided calling package not found: com.google.android.apps.photos
    03-19 08:28:52.273 1319-1954/com.google.android.gms E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.wearable.settings
    03-19 08:28:52.605 984-984/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null
    03-19 08:28:52.889 1319-1954/com.google.android.gms E/ProcessCheckinRequest: CheckinNowTaskTag : Checkin Succeeded: https://android.clients.google.com/checkin (request #1): 
    03-19 08:28:56.659 598-651/system_process E/SupplicantWifiScannerImpl: Failed to start scan, freqs={2412}
    03-19 08:28:56.659 598-648/system_process E/WifiConnectivityManager: SingleScanListener onFailure: reason: -1 description: Scan failed
    03-19 08:29:01.659 598-651/system_process E/SupplicantWifiScannerImpl: Failed to start scan, freqs={2412}
    03-19 08:29:01.660 598-648/system_process E/WifiConnectivityManager: SingleScanListener onFailure: reason: -1 description: Scan failed
    03-19 08:29:06.661 598-651/system_process E/SupplicantWifiScannerImpl: Failed to start scan, freqs={2412}
    03-19 08:29:06.661 598-648/system_process E/WifiConnectivityManager: SingleScanListener onFailure: reason: -1 description: Scan failed
    03-19 08:29:11.661 598-651/system_process E/SupplicantWifiScannerImpl: Failed to start scan, freqs={2412}
    03-19 08:29:11.661 598-648/system_process E/WifiConnectivityManager: SingleScanListener onFailure: reason: -1 description: Scan failed
    03-19 08:29:16.663 598-651/system_process E/SupplicantWifiScannerImpl: Failed to start scan, freqs={2412}
    03-19 08:29:16.663 598-648/system_process E/WifiConnectivityManager: SingleScanListener onFailure: reason: -1 description: Scan failed
    03-19 08:29:22.127 2106-2106/com.google.android.gms:car E/CAR.TEL.Service: Failed to bind to InCallService
    03-19 08:29:22.393 1508-1508/com.android.vending E/Finsky: [1] com.google.android.finsky.wear.bl.a(3): onConnectionFailed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null, message=null}
    03-19 08:29:33.709 598-628/system_process E/PackageInstaller: Commit of session 1175500126 failed: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113
    03-19 08:29:33.723 1508-1508/com.android.vending E/Finsky: [1] com.google.android.finsky.cb.a.n.onReceive(27): Error -507 while installing com.android.vending: INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113
    03-19 08:29:38.209 2166-2173/com.android.deskclock E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
    03-19 08:30:01.102 1319-1738/com.google.android.gms E/SQLiteCastStore: End saving paired guest mode devices
    03-19 08:30:01.127 244-244/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/1814/oom_score_adj; errno=22
    03-19 08:32:15.534 2221-2221/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
    03-19 08:32:15.534 2221-2221/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
    03-19 08:32:15.761 2236-2236/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
    03-19 08:32:15.761 2236-2236/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
03-19 08:32:22.313 255-260/? E/Drm: Failed to find drm plugin
```

It looks like I am having some dependency issues. So I cleaned and rebuilt the project, still running into the same errors. I know for a fact it was compiling before it was pushed to Git.

Comment: (Aside: please don't advise people how to vote here, or tell them they're "lazy" for not justifying their downvotes - that is asking for trouble. This material does not belong in posts anyway, as it is not useful for readers).